# Calculate $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y) $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Calculate $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y) $ of
$$ f(x,y) = \int_{x^2}^{y^2} e^{-t^2}\, dt$$

Comment: Do you mean $\partial f / \partial x$?

Comment: **Hint** : 

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} g(t) dt = g(x) $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us call $E=E(t)$ a fixed antiderivative of $e^{-t^2}$. Then $$f(x,y)=E(y^2)-E(x^2).$$ Now, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( E(y^2)-E(x^2) \right) = -2x E'(x^2)=-2x e^{-x^4}.$$